# How to keep the table contents after changing scenes in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm currently trying to design a booking system. After selecting their preferred choices, the user will click "Confirm" and their data will be placed into a tableview. However, after I click back to return to homepage and returning back to the booking page, the data is all gone. Is there a way to preserve the data in the table after I leave the scene so that when I return back to the booking page, the data will still be

This is my Booking controller:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CheckBookingController implements Initializable {

    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    
    @FXML
    private Button btnBack;

    @FXML
    private Button btnConfirm;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker btnDate;

    @FXML
    private Label dateStatus;
    
    @FXML
    private Label peopleStatus;

    @FXML
    private Label roomName;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Table> tableview;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> timeBox;
    
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> peopleBox;

    @FXML
    private Label timeStatus;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtField;
    
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Table, String> timeColumn;
    
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Table, String> peopleColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Table, String> roomColumn;
    
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Table, String> dateColumn;
    
    
    
    
    private String[] time = {"10-11","11-12","12-1"}; // values for combo box
    private String[] people = {"1","2","3","4","5"}; //values for combo box

    @FXML
    public void onBackClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException { // back button to return home
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainPage.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    void onBoxSelect(ActionEvent event) { //combo box with time
        String theTime = timeBox.getValue();
        timeStatus.setText(theTime);
    }
    
    @FXML
    void onPeopleSelect(ActionEvent event) { //combo box with number of people
        String thePeople = peopleBox.getValue();
        peopleStatus.setText(thePeople);
    }

    @FXML
    void onConfirmClicked(ActionEvent event) { //confirm button to store data into table
        Table table = new Table (roomName.getText(), dateStatus.getText(), timeStatus.getText(), peopleStatus.getText()); //roomName is just a label to get text from
        ObservableList<Table> tableAdd = tableview.getItems();
        tableAdd.add(table);
        tableview.setItems(tableAdd);
    }

    @FXML
    void onDateClicked(ActionEvent event) { //date picker
        LocalDate date = btnDate.getValue();
        String formattedDate = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
        dateStatus.setText(formattedDate);
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        timeBox.getItems().addAll(time);
        timeBox.setOnAction(this::onBoxSelect);
        
        peopleBox.getItems().addAll(people);
        peopleBox.setOnAction(this::onPeopleSelect);
        
        timeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("time"));
        dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("date"));
        roomColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("room"));
        peopleColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("people"));
    }
//after selecting data, the user clicks confirm and all the data from both combo box and date picker will be stored into the table. 

}
```

This is my Table.java:

```
package application;

public class Table {
    
    private String room;
    private String date;
    private String time;
    private String people;
    
    public Table(String room, String date, String time, String people){
        this.room = room;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.people = people;
    }
    
    public String getRoom() {
        return room;
    }
    
    public void setRoom(String room) {
        this.room = room;
    }
    
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    
    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    
    public String getPeople() {
        return people;
    }
    
    public void setPeople(String people) {
        this.people = people;
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider using a MVC design, so the data are persisted in the model, no matter what view is displayed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx (or many other resources)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying MVC With JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx)

Comment: for your next question: always provide a [mcve] when showing code (vs. a whole lot of unrelated fluff)